# How to modify the metavar for a positional argument in pythons argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

In the *argparse* package the `metavar` parameter modifies the displayed help message of a program. The following program is not intended to work, it is simply used to demonstrate the behavior of the `metavar` parameter.

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Print a range.")

    parser.add_argument("-range1", nargs = 3, type = int, help = "Specify range with: start, stop, step.", metavar = ("start", "stop", "step"))
    parser.add_argument("-range2", nargs = 3, type = int, help = "Specify range with: start, stop, step.", metavar = "r2")
```

The corresponding help message is:

```
usage: main.py [-h] [-range1 start stop step] [-range2 r2 r2 r2]

Print a range.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -range1 start stop step
                        Specify range with: start, stop, step.
  -range2 r2 r2 r2      Specify range with: start, stop, step.
```

Please note the differences behind `-range1` and `-range2`. Clearly `-range1` is the preferred way of the help message.

Up to this point everything is clear to me. However, if I change the optional `-range1` argument to a positional `range1` argument, *argparse* cannot deal with the tuple of the `metavar` parameter (`ValueError: too many values to unpack`).
The only way I was able to get it work was in the way `-range2` is done. But then the help message is by far not as good as for the `-range1` case.

Is there a way to get the same help message as for the `-range1` case but for a positional argument instead of an optional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Print a range.")

    parser.add_argument("start", type = int, help = "Specify start.", )
    parser.add_argument("stop", type = int, help = "Specify stop.", )
    parser.add_argument("step", type = int, help = "Specify step.", )

    args=parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

which yields

```
% test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] start stop step

Print a range.

positional arguments:
  start       Specify start.
  stop        Specify stop.
  step        Specify step.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Hi unutbu,
I think I will implement it like you suggested. However, I feel that the connection between those three parameters might not be so clear as it would be if they were grouped into "one" parameter.

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, you could add more explanation, such as `description='''Prints a range. %(prog)s start stop step prints start, start+step, start+2*step, ..., start+n*step where n is the greatest integer such that start+n*stop<stop. For example, %(prog)s 1 4 2 prints...'''`

Answer (score 5):

> However, if I change the optional -range1 argument to a positional range1 argument, argparse cannot deal with the tuple of the metavar parameter (ValueError: too many values to unpack).

argparse shouldn't be giving that `too many values to unpack` error message.  It's produced by `metavar, = self._metavar_formatter(action, default)(1)`.  Normally this function produces a single item list or tuple, but in your case it returns the tuple metavar.  It needs to give a more informative error message (`tuple metavar not allowed with positionals` ?), or gracefully adapt the metavar (`start|stop|step` ?).  Another option is to use the default metavar in the help line instead of the tuple.

The tuple metavar works ok on the usage line.

I think the help formatting was written with uniform positionals in mind.  On the usage line it might show `X [X [X ...]]`, but on the help line just `X ...   description of X`.

Your 3 items have distinct names, so unutbu's suggestion of 3 separate positionals is probably what the argparse designers had in mind.

This issue has been raised (but not patched)

http://bugs.python.org/issue14074
"argparse allows nargs>1 for positional arguments but doesn't allow metavar to be a tuple"